# parse key=val list where space has dual meaning (separator and part of val)

Tags: python, linux, macos, parsing, environment-variables

I'm looking for extracting the environment variables from remote process by parsing `ps eww` output directly (denote that there are libraries such as psutils but I'd rather not use them)

for example:

if I run `a="foo bar" b=b sleep 100` than `ps eww | grep sleep` will return something like :

```
sleep 100 a=foo bar b=b ...
```

So the output in this case should be :

```
dict = {"a" : "foo bar", b" : "b" }
```

So far I simply took this output and use `split` according to the default space delimiter. but space is a valid parameter (notice that space can also be part of the value and the delimiter between 2 variables from key=val format.

Any idea who to split it into key=val struct so that spaces are also valid character of value name (but not valid for key name) ?

Comment: This dict is what `psutil.Process().environ` gives you directly, and without you having to worry about environment variables whose values contain special characters (space, newline, `=`). Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input string by spaces (as you did). Then for each substring, check if it contains the `=` character. If so, add this as a new key-value pair; if not, append the substring to the value for the previous key.

Code:

```
dict = {}
key = ''
for s in input.split():
  if '=' in s:
    key, val = s.split('=')
    dict.update({key : val})
  else:
    if key in dict:
      dict[key] += ' ' + s
```